# Prints in teardown in Pycharm is not seen

Tags: pycharm, pytest

When a test fails, I wish to print information about my setup in the teardown. However, I cannot see the output in Pycharm in the failing test case **after teardown**. However, I see the print in the setup.

What to do to see the print in the teardown?

**Minimal example:**

my_test.py

```py
import pytest
    
    
@pytest.mark.parametrize("number_a", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
def test_a_low_numbers(number_a):
   run_test(number_a=number_a)
    
    
def run_test(number_a):
   assert number_a != 4
```

conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def signal_handler(request, number_a):
   print("########Setup")
   yield
   print("########Teardown information is now printed")
```

Pycharm console:
[image: The string "########Teardown" is never printed)]

Comment: If you click on the `test_a_low_numbers` suite and on on the individual parametrized execution, then you'll see the teardown - it's just a pycharm issue not adding the printing to the test execution.

Comment: I've seen I can see it there, but when running several tests, it's hard to match test cases with the output.